Pass data from ngx-bootstrap modal which is child component to parent component
I have seperate child component which in ngx-bootstrap modal here i have defined @input @output properties
  @Input() public openFrom;
  @Output() selecteduse = new EventEmitter<any>();

from parent component i'm opening this modal
const modalRef=this.modalServiceNew.show(ListComponent, { class: "model",   ...this.modOpt   })

but need some way to catch some event
previously through ng-bootstrap was doing like this but in ngx-bootstrap facing issues

for sending data :

modalRef.componentInstance.openFrom="form name";


for receiving event:

modalRef.componentInstance.selecteduse.subscribe(($e) => {
   thid.func1();
})


Any solution Thanks

what issue you are having with this method, what you want different?

@NarenMurali I want to achieve same in ngx-bootstrap, i want to pass data from parent component to modal which is child component and vice-versa

If you check the docs there is a property called content which you can use to achieve the same.
This content exists only if you open a component, it will be null, if you open with a ng-template.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService, ModalOptions } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
 
@Component({
  // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/component-selector
  selector: 'demo-modal-service-component',
  templateUrl: './service-component.html'
})
export class DemoModalServiceFromComponent {
  bsModalRef?: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}
 
  openModalWithComponent() {
    const initialState: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {
        list: ['Open a modal with component', 'Pass your data', 'Do something else', '...'],
        title: 'Modal with component'
      }
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show<ModalContentComponent>(ModalContentComponent, initialState);
    this.bsModalRef.content.openFrom="form name";
    this.bsModalRef.content.selecteduse.subscribe(($e) => {
       thid.func1();
    })
  }
}


can you pls check the above screenshot i'm getting error this selecteduse exist in child component which is popup

@user3653474 updated my answer,  did it work?

Thanks it is working but it is mandatory to pass initialState i want to pass class and other ModalOptions

@user3653474 I dont think its mandatory, try without it, or just pass empty object

Done can you pls let me know is initialState mandatory i want to pass this option  modOpt: ModalOptions = {     backdrop: 'static',     keyboard: false,    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',     ignoreBackdropClick: true,    id: 1  } as parameter and class name

@user3653474 its not mandatory source code
